# Server Version of "tonido" or "opera unite"?

Tags: nas, opera

[Tonido](http://www.tonido.com/) and [opera unite](http://unite.opera.com/overview/), seem to be written for Desktop environments. (tonido may be run under windowless environment, but it only provides 32bit version. I am afraid of crashing the dependent libraries)

Are there any similar services that can run on servers?

Comment: I am one of the developers of Tonido. Do you have a specific requirement ? If you are just worried about compatibility of Tonido, The 32bit versions are fully compatible in 64bit environment. In fact, my personal server runs on 64bit windows 7 and in 64bit Linux.

Comment: When I tried to install, I found that it needs to replace openssl 64 bit library by 32 bit library. This is my concern. I hope that there will be 64bit version of Tonido :)

Comment: The latest release has libssl bundled in. so you wouldnt have to do that.

Answer (score 1):

There are various opensource applications for NAS, and most of them can be configured via web interface. Try one of these and pick out your favorite: FreeNAS, CryptoNAS, NASLite, Gluster, Openfiler, OpenMediaVault.

If your server is Ubuntu, TurnKey should be preferred.

Another thing is Opera Unite is not actually a NAS, it is just a peer to peer sharing and Opera will keep an eye on your data.

Comment: Opera Unite is closer to a local file server kind of sharing. Like if you would have put a Filezilla server on your computer. Everything is hosted on your machine, and I don't see why Opera would have access to it. All they do is provide the URL to access it, from what I experienced.

Comment: The solutions are good, but they are in OS level. It may be not that suitable for my case.